# Passing flask textbox value to an infinite while loop

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, textbox

I'm running a flask server, with a textbox input and a while loop (in a different thread). I want to pass the input value from the textbox to the while loop.

This is the .py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import thread
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
def main():
    
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print "var = "+str(var)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    
    templateData = {
        'var': var 

    }
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    
    global var 
    var = 0
    var = int(request.form['var'])
    return str("var: " + str(var))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread.start_new_thread(main, ()) 
    thread.start_new_thread(post, ()) 
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8083, debug=True)
```

This is the .html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>POST</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <form method="POST">
        var:<br>
        <input name="var">   
        <br><br>
        Current:    {{ var  }} <br><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is the proper way to get the value to the while loop, because I'm getting mixed signals in the loop. If I for example write 3 in the textbox I'll get...

```
var = 0
var = 3
var = 0
var = 3
var = 0
var = 3
var = 0
var = 3
```

...in the while loop, because it's first reading var = 0 and then var = int(request.form['var'])

Comment: have you tried to remove `var = 0` ?

Comment: I get an error message.....
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "New.py", line 10, in main 
  print "var = "+str(var)
NameError: global name 'var' is not defined
.....I need to define var even before it is entered into the textbox

Comment: cvr cvr cvr cvr